# How to stop to access /system/../ directory from user application in android

Tags: android, android-source, selinux

I am working AOSP M version.

I have created a test directory in the system partition. like below,
/system/test/

Only system applications can read the data from /system/test/ directory, presently the User applications also reading data from /system/test directory.

How can we stop reading data from user applications, only system applications read the data from /system/test/ directry.

I have done below steps :

Step1 : Created test_file in below location

android/vendor/xyz/prebuilts/bin/

Step2 : android/vendor/xyz/prebuilts/bin/Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := test_file

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE)

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := test

LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/test

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

When I have compiled the AOSP code , test_file generated in out directory android/out/target/product/abc/system/test_file

Step3 : Registered in file in file_contexts
/android/vendor/xyz/abc/sepolicy/file_contexts

/system/test/test_file u:object_r:abc_test_file:s0

Step4 : Added below line in the path of android/vendor/abc/xyz/sepolicy/file.te

type abc_test_file, file_type;

Coipled the source code and flashed image into device ,

Executed below command in android device shell,

abc@123#ls /system/test/test_test -lZ
-rw-r--r-- root     root              u:object_r:abc_test_file:s0 test_file

Could you please suggest me , where I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the DAC for /system/test.
Look at example from google:
[device/google/sunfish/config.fs](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/google/sunfish/config.fs;l=77?q=config.fs)

```
[system/vendor/bin/loc_launcher]
mode: 0755
user:  AID_GPS
group: AID_GPS
caps: SETUID SETGID
```

And there is an [doc](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/filesystem) about how to custom DAC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Yong. I have changes in config.fs, it is doing both user& system application is not able to access or both user and system application can access. But for me, only system applications should access the data, and user applications should not access the data.

Comment: Yes. You can only set user to a known uid, eg AID_SYSTEM.  or you can define an oem uid.

Comment: I have added this line 00771, AID_SYSTEM, AID_SYSTEM, 0, "/system/test/test_file" in infs_config.c file, but user application also getting access test_file.

Comment: Change mode to 0700

Comment: If I change the permission to 0700, the system application also not able to access the  "/system/test/test_file" file.

Comment: Yes, only application with system uid can access the file, not system application.

Comment: in my system application already added android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the androidmanifest.xml file, could you please suggest to me where I have done wrong.

Comment: ls -lZ /system/test/test_file. Make sure that it has take effects. And ps to see whether your app have the system uid.

Comment: it seems not taking effect in file permissions ,                                                                           ls -lZ /system/test/test_file responce is ----> -rw-r--r-- root     root              u:object_r:system_file:s0 test_file

Comment: my system app ps reponce is -----> system    4361  2416  903440 46008 SyS_epoll_ b6c82 S com.test.test

Comment: Do you have add "TARGET_FS_CONFIG_GEN += device/x/y/config.fs"

Comment: In my AOSP source code config.fs file is not available, I have added those changes in fs_config.c

Comment: I have updated question in detail , could you please check

Comment: Do you add seplicy rule for abc_test_file? eg: allow priv_app abc_test_file:file { getattr read write };

Comment: No, I haven't added. Could you please suggest to me? which .te file I need add allow priv_app abc_test_file:file { getattr read write };.  Not able to find priv_app In my total codebase.

Comment: Add in vendor/xyz/abc/sepolicy/priv_app.te. priv_app is the domain for app in /system/priv-app without known uid, eg system uid. Google seapp_contexts to find more details.

Comment: Hi Yong, Thanks for your support. I have created a new fs_config.c in AOSP, given proper permission, and given the system for owner and group. Now I am able to access file only for system applications.